# Can't get GetModuleFileNameA to work, keep getting error 'missing type specifier...'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to use 'GetModuleFileNameA' but I keep getting the error 'c4430: missing type specifier - int assumed'.  From reading the results from my google search I am guessing that it is from my use of NULL:

```
char Filename[MAX_PATH]; //this is a char buffer
GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, Filename, sizeof(Filename));
```

NULL is supposedly defined in #include stdio.h which I have included in my project, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: That snippet compiles fine. Which line is the error being reported for? Is it actually coming from either of those two lines?

Comment: It is very unlikely that this error has anything to do with NULL (for which the correct include would be `<cstdlib>` or `<cstddef>`, AFAIK): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696.aspx. You should post a more complete example, together with all the includes.

Comment: Thank you.  It was totally my fault being a moron.  I am working on someone else's code and was trying to test a piece by putting it in a seperate .dll project.  I had used an empty project and forgotten to put function header around the test code (I was tired and staying with family, so rushing) and I simply forgot...  Thank you, if nothing else you made me look at what I was doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried GetModuleFileNameA(GetModuleHandle(0),Filename,sizeof(Filename)) ?

From [MSDN GetModuleFileName description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

```
The global variable _pgmptr is automatically initialized to the full path of the executable file, and can be used to retrieve the full path name of an executable file.
```

You might want to check if this value out, and if you need it, how does it behave in multi-library environment.

Comment: Thanks, see my comment above, interesting link and I will check it out.  I like posting here because just getting 'slapped' around a little bit makes you take a proper look at what you are doing.  Thanks.  And yes, to answer your question I had tried what you were suggesting :)